# How do I clear my csv file but keep header using PHP cron jobs?

Tags: php, csv, cron

I'm trying to create a cron job using PHP script that clears my file.csv but excludes the header?

I've tried this link but no luck:
[How To Delete The Top 100 Rows From a CSV File With PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095320/how-to-delete-the-top-100-rows-from-a-csv-file-with-php)

Here's my code:

```
function csv_delete_rows($filename='/home/marketingapi/public_html/test.csv', $startrow=0, $endrow=0, $inner=true) {
    $status = 0;
    //check if file exists
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
    //end execution for invalid startrow or endrow
        if ($startrow < 0 || $endrow < 0 || $startrow > 0 && $endrow > 0 && $startrow > $endrow) {
            die('Invalid startrow or endrow value');
        }
        $updatedcsv = array();
        $count = 0;
        //open file to read contents
        $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
        //loop to read through csv contents
        while ($csvcontents = fgetcsv($fp)) {
            $count++;
            if ($startrow > 0 && $endrow > 0) {
                //delete rows inside startrow and endrow
                if ($inner) {
                    $status = 1;
                        if ($count >= $startrow && $count <= $endrow)
                            continue;
                        array_push($updatedcsv, implode(',', $csvcontents));
                }else{
                    //delete rows outside startrow and endrow
                    $status = 2;
                    if ($count < $startrow || $count > $endrow)
                        continue;
                
                    array_push($updatedcsv, implode(',', $csvcontents));
                }
            } else if ($startrow == 0 && $endrow > 0) {
                $status = 3;
                if ($count <= $endrow)
                    continue;
        
                array_push($updatedcsv, implode(',', $csvcontents));
            } else if ($endrow == 0 && $startrow > 0) {
                $status = 4;
                if ($count >= $startrow)
                    continue;
        
                array_push($updatedcsv, implode(',', $csvcontents));
            } else if ($startrow == 0 && $endrow == 0) {
                $status = 5;
            } else {
                $status = 6;
            }
        }//end while
        if ($status < 5) {
            $finalcsvfile = implode("\n", $updatedcsv);
            fclose($fp);
            $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
            fwrite($fp, $finalcsvfile);
        }
        fclose($fp);
        return $status;
    } else {
        die('File does not exist');
    }
}
```

Comment: read the first line, close the file, delete the file, Open the file for Write, write the first line into the file. close the file **simples**

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, Sorry I couldn't get this to work, cron tasks isn't running it?

Comment: _couldn't get this to work_ Why? Have you got error messages. Maybe if you show your code we could be more use to you

Comment: @RiggsFolly code added, I'm running this in cron jobs. The cron job doesn't activate and run when I insert this code?

Answer (score 0):

Just truncate the file after the first line:

```
<?php 
   $f = fopen('myfile.csv', 'r+') or die();
   flock($f, LOCK_EX); // lock the file to avoid parallel scripts altering it
   fgetcsv($f); // read the first line)
   ftruncate($f, ftell($f)); // truncate the file to where the file pointer is
   flock($f, LOCK_UN); // unlock
   fclose($f);
```

Comment: Hi @AterLux thanks, do I insert this before the function on the original code?